# does Direct 2D leaves pointers in the memory?

Tags: c++, directx, direct2d

Obviously, working with Direct X, we are heavily working with pointers, but the question I couldn't find on MSDN is: does Direct X create memory with "new" internally?

Example:

```
ID2D1GeometrySink * pSink;

path->Open(&pSink); // did this command use "new" internally?
```

In MSDN, they only used `pSink = NULL`, to create multiple sinks from the same variable. So will be there any memory leak?

Comment: The documentation does not seem to mention having to free the `ID2D1GeometrySink*` when done using it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As DirectX uses COM it must follow COM rules of maintaining memory.

So if a method returns an interface pointer, a caller is responsible for releasing this pointer.

In general, we never know nature of the returned pointer. In this particular case we don't know whether ID2D1GeometrySink allocated within this method, or this is a precreated object. All what you need to know about managing returned pointer is that you should call Release when you don't need this pointer.

Also I would suggest to use wrappers that call Release in destructor, I mean classes like CComPtr and others. In this case you don't need to call AddRef / Release yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few questions here.

Yes, the call to `path->Open` allocates resources for your sink.  `pSink` is a pointer but you pass `&pSink` to the `Open` method - a pointer to the pointer.  The call obtains a geometry sink and sets your `pSink` variable to point to that sink.  It can do this because you have passed the address of your pointer rather than the value of the pointer.

Will it leak memory?

Yes, if you don't release the sink when you are done with it.  [The examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee264309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#create_a_path_geometry_for_the_right_mountain) are clear on this, calling `SafeRelease(&pSink);` when finished with the object.